# SVG + javascript click and drag slow

Tags: javascript, performance, svg, svg.js

Apologies if this requires a little explanation, but it's probably quite a niche problem.

I have a large SVG graph in html/js, maintained by SVG.js.

Initially, performance is ok, even with 230 nodes. However, after I perform a large number of operations on it, performance starts to slow, even as the node count hasn't increased.

It'll take some time to create minimally sufficient code but you can take a look for yourself here:

1. Go to https://acenturyandabit.github.io/polymorph/
2. Click 'itemcluster 2' after skipping the tutorial
3. Double click to add items, shift-click and drag to connect items to form a graph. Add 20 or so connected nodes.
4. Drag an empty space to pan the view. It should be pretty fast.
5. Right click on an empty space and click 'Arrange in hierarchy' a couple dozen times.
6. Drag and pan again. It starts jarring...

Does anyone know why this happens? Is it a SVG.js thing? Is it a javascript thing?

Thanks

Comment: Where is synergist 2?

Comment: presumably there's some kind of leak of objects in Arrange in hierarchy. Without a [mcve] it's going to be hard to help you any further.

Comment: Itemcluster 2, my bad - i need to make my naming conventions conssitent

Comment: I didnt have any issues by trying that. You should profile the code and see where the time is spend to find the leak